# npgsql connection wait with ssl

Tags: vb.net, ssl, npgsql

I setup a listener for notification from postresql through npgsql in vb.net. The sub just opens a new ssl connection and starts a new thread with a loop waiting for notification. Here below is the code

```
Public Sub StartListening()
    If mConnString Is Nothing Then
        Main_Form.WriteMessage("Not connected")
    End If
    Try
        connection = New NpgsqlConnection(mConnString) With {
            .ProvideClientCertificatesCallback = New ProvideClientCertificatesCallback(AddressOf MyProvideClientCertificates)
        }
        connection.Open()
        If connection.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Using command = New NpgsqlCommand("listen my_notification", connection)
                command.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End If

        AddHandler connection.Notification, New NotificationEventHandler(AddressOf OnNotification)
        Dim thread As New Thread(
            Sub()
                While True
                    connection.Wait()
                End While
            End Sub
        )
        thread.Start()

    Catch ex As Exception
        Main_Form.WriteMessage("Error:" +  ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub


Private Sub MyProvideClientCertificates(ByVal clienteCertis As X509CertificateCollection)
    Dim cert As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2("mycertificate.pfx")
    clienteCertis.Add(cert)
End Sub
```

Everything was working fine until I introduced SSL connection: it fails on **connection.Wait()** saying

> Wait() with timeout isn't supported when SSL is used, see
>   https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1501

Since actually I don't need a timeout I tried setting **timeout=0** and **commandtimeout=0** in connection string but error still remains and this is what I see in error stacktrace

> in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Wait(Int32 timeout)
>
> in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Wait(Int32 timeout)
>
> in Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Wait()

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. I write here just in case some else has the same problem.

I changed **Wait()** with **WaitAsync()**.

To avoid continuous looping also added **Await** and declare the sub as **Async**.

Below is the code

```
        ....
        Dim thread As New Thread(
            Async Sub()
                While True
                    Await connection.WaitAsync()
                End While
            End Sub
        )
        thread.Start()
        ....
```